# CSS center floating li

Tags: html, css

I have ul where **li** elements are **floating left**. I want to align those li elements to center of ul.

### Goal:

[image: before] ======>>>    [image: after]

### My try:

My try always result this

[image: my]

### Jsbin:

http://jsbin.com/EGoVAg/19/edit

### EDIT:

### width of #wrapper is not fixed ! I use 320px just to show you result pictures !

Comment: Can't you just set the elements just set to `display: inline-block;` and use `text-align: center;`?

Comment: @feeela that result to picture #3

Comment: Then you don't have enough space in the horizontal space; check your paddings and borders;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your only option is to set a fixed width and do:

```
#wrapper {
 display: block;
 margin: 0 auto; /* center it */
 width: XXX;
}
```

You can use media queries to set the fixed width at certain breakpoints, if you like, or you could use `max-width` instead of `width`

http://jsbin.com/EGoVAg/23/edit

You may not like this answer (judging by your large font, bolded comment about #wrapper not being a fixed width), but there is no other way to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, remove the `float: left;` from `.widgetPhotoGallery li.photo`. `display: inline-block` (which is already included) is all you need to correctly position the elements:

```css
.widgetPhotoGallery li.photo{
    background-color: blue;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Then all you need to do is simply give your `ul` some padding (`36px` evens out both sides):

```
.widgetPhotoGallery .photogallery{
    background-color: lime;
    list-style: none;
    padding:0 36px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: left;
}
```

[**Working JSBin demo**](http://jsbin.com/EGoVAg/9/edit).

On a side note, you don't need *any* of those `!important` declarations. The styling is identical without them. If you need to override existing styling you should look into [CSS Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) instead.

Comment: -1 for `!important` (Reverted, since the alternative version was added)

Comment: @Grevling I have implemented glogal options for li elements in that class, there for I need to rewrite them in this case

Comment: @feela `!important` is in OP's code. This isn't anything I've added.

Comment: @Ing.MichalHudak you should look into [CSS specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity). `!important` is almost always a bad idea.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly I know, but circumstances made me do it. Thanks for concerns :)

Comment: Your answer doesn't resolve the problem. Your solution does what OP described as "My try". He needs what he described as the second image in "Goal".

Comment: @matewka I think you must have been looking at a different link.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set a fixed width to the `ul`. So in your example, each `li` has **118px** of width and **2px** of margin on each side. To fit two `li`'s in a row set this to `.widgetPhotoGallery .photogallery`:

```
width: 244px;
```

Notice that the background will become smaller, so you can simply put it to `.widgetPhotoGallery .widgetContent`

```
.widgetPhotoGallery .widgetContent {
    background-color: lime;
}
```

**[Here's the update JSbin](http://jsbin.com/EGoVAg/11/edit)**.

Comment: I cant set fixed width

Comment: @Ing.MichalHudak, can you explain why? Because what you're trying to achieve here is probably impossible without fixed width.

Comment: @matewka I put code in #wrapper so you can see what I need, try to think that width is in %, then what ? Example: wrapper with is 100%.

Comment: @Adam, it won't resolve the problem. OP wants the `li`s to be aligned to the left.

Comment: @matewka - my bad. I misread the question like the other answer.

Comment: @matewka - Believe me, I already tried, but I can't unless the answer is edited.